# ejabberd 16.01 muc and mam mode

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

On ejabberd 16.01, is it possible to store entire group messages history (muc mode) in odbc using mam mode?

I can see that created room are stored in persistent database but I am wondering can message history be stored as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to archive group messages using mod_mam
you can simple install mod_mam and configure ejabberd like this:

```
  mod_mam: 
    default: always
```

with setting default to always it will archive all messages including MUC messages.